# Sharepoint 2013 User Profile Service Error

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-service

We have setup SharePoint 2013 with SQL 2014.
2014 June CU is also installed.

Since my previous attempts failed, I tried to set up `user profile service` using the farm account. It is a local admin account and given log on locally privilege. And made sysadmin in the SQL DB (an act of desperation).

I did not find PowerShell profiles created in any of the locations retired by running the script

```
"$PROFILE | Format-List -Force".
```

After creation of the proxy and the service application, when I try to start the service,

> it either stops or stays stuck in "starting" stage.

I have a separate account to read the AD with the privileges. But to set up a connection I have to get the service running, so I can't enter that account.

Can somebody let me know what am I doing wrong and point me in the right direction?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are more reasons regarding this issue like

- the farm account is not added to local administrator group during starting and provisioning UPS service.
- the User Profile Sync Service account is not a member of Farm Administrator group.
- Forefront Identity Manager Service is not running.

and SO on...

In the following articles, I found out details reasons list and how to solve it,  Hope it helps you.

- [User Profile Synchronization Service Stuck on ‘Starting’](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/user-profile-sync-service-stuck-on-starting/)
- [User Profile Synchronization Service Starting then Stopped in SharePoint](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/user-profile-synchronization-service-starting-and-stoped/).

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't given "Replicating Directory changes" authority to the farm admin. So the service failed. I thought we have to give that permission only to the Synchronization connection user.